# ASP.NET MVC 4 CSS @import attribute

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

As a developer in learning process I'm having an issue with my CSS files using Bundles in MVC 4.

I know a couple of things that I think are important:

- When I change the debug value to false in the principal web.config the CSS and JS files that I put in the BundleConfig.cs class are automaticaly minimize.
- I read that someone says that it's important to put the exact name of the CSS and JS files to avoid them to be loaded more that once. I don't realy know if that is true but I prefer to write the exact file name. I will apreciate some aditional information about.

Now the isse is this.

I have two CSS files:

fileOne.css

```
// fileOne.css
@import url("_fileTwo.css");

.body{
    background: blue;
}
```

_fileTwo.css

```
// _fileTwo.css
.header{
  color: red;
}
```

Now the problem is that when I call fileOne.css in the bundle and I put in the web.config the debug attribute in false the Bundle put this message in the generated CSS file.

```
/* Error de minimización. Devolviendo el contenido no minimizado.
(430,1): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '@import'
(430,9): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found 'url(_fileTwo.css)'
 */
```

When I put the _fileTwo .css in the BundleConfig.cs class this is loaded and minimize perfectly.

The reason why I am creating a CSS sub file is because I want everything to be in perfectly order and separated from the others. You know "Divide and conquer".

The thing I want to know is this.
Do I have to put my CSS sub files in the Bundle?
Is there a way to use @import attribute in CSS using MVC Bundles?

Thanks so much for reading this, and please sorry my english.

Comment: Unfortunately `@import` is not supported by default. What you can do is to remove the `@import` and put both css files in the same bundle in `BundleConfig.cs`.

Comment: I see... It is not supported by default but it is possible to do?

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback. No I can't do it but another thing is that the company where I work we use visual studio 2012 and the MVC version of this one is MVC3, right? I'm not sure if I can use the import in another new MVC version. Thanks for your interest guys.

Answer (score 0):

Definetly I'll recomend to use any CSS compiler like SASS or LESS for styling in CSS and specificaly when you need to use @import. This because @import have more advantages in this compilers.